# F# and Silverlight 5: out-of-browser with elevated trust?

Tags: silverlight, f#, out-of-browser, elevated-privileges

Currently, I'm using Daniel Mohl's "F# Web Application (Silverlight)" extension to create a Silverlight app entirely in F# (Visual Studio 2010).

I need to do local file I/O (which obviously requires elevated trust), and I'd like to run the app out-of-browser as well, but I'm not able to set this up in the normal fashion (e.g. as I can in Daniel Mohl's "F# C# Web App (Silverlight)" extension), since the project settings in the all-F# configuration don't offer the necessary settings.

Can I set this up by making a few simple modifications to the project file in a text editor, or are there more steps involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an OutOfBrowserSettings.xml file to your project:

```
<OutOfBrowserSettings ShortName="App" ShowInstallMenuItem="True">
 <OutOfBrowserSettings.Blurb>App blurb</OutOfBrowserSettings.Blurb>
 <OutOfBrowserSettings.WindowSettings>
  <WindowSettings Title="App Title" />
 </OutOfBrowserSettings.WindowSettings>
 <OutOfBrowserSettings.Icons />
</OutOfBrowserSettings>
```

Then add the following tags to your .fsproj file under PropertyGroup:

```
<EnableOutOfBrowser>true</EnableOutOfBrowser>
<OutOfBrowserSettingsFile>OutOfBrowserSettings.xml</OutOfBrowserSettingsFile>
```